# Yammer.connect.embedFeed - starting a new conversation with a page URL that already belongs to another conversation

Tags: yammer

Here's the scenario: we're using yammer connect on an internal website for a specific team that has it's own yammer group. This website displays thousands of "items" and yammer is used to manage discussions about each item using the url (e.g. http://somesite/item?id=123). All was going well until someone in a different yammer group created a conversation and used a URL that points to a page in my internal website (e.g. http://somesite/item?id=123). So now when users go to that item they see a conversation for a different group.

I'm using the defaultGroupID in the config argument, but is there a way to tell yammer to ristrict it to a specific group id - and create a new conversation for that group only for the given URL (if one doesn't exist)? Can yammer even create multiple conversations in different groups regarding the same url - but keep the conversations restricted to each group?

Here's a code sample of how I'm creating the conversations:

```js
    var varYammerTargetUrl = $('#hidYammerTargetUrl').val();
    var varYammerGroupId = $('#hidYammerGroupId').val(); 
    var objProps = { url: varYammerTargetUrl, type: 'page', title: document.title };
    
    yam.connect.embedFeed({
 container: '#yammerFeed', network: 'mycompany.com', feedType: 'open-graph', feedId: '',
 config: {
     use_sso: false
     , header: false
     , footer: false
     , showOpenGraphPreview: false
     , defaultToCanonical: false
     , hideNetworkName: false
     , defaultGroupId: varYammerGroupId
     , promptText: 'Start a conversation about this concession'
 }
     , objectProperties: objProps
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

When URLs are posted into Yammer there is an open graph object created. These objects don't live in groups by design and thus can be created anywhere within Yammer and are not restricted to certain groups.

Here is some additional documentation.